# Chrome при выполнении JS скрипта в консоли останавливаться логика активной страницы

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Доброе. "Пытаюсь" сделать скрипт на js который нажимает нужные кнопки(с логикой) на странице.

Алгоритм таков :

- скрипт нажимает кнопку 1 после выходит окошко, в котором надо нажать кнопку 2 ,
- окно должно пропасть и поменяться данные на странице.

Вопрос : когда я запускаю свой скрипт в консоли, то логика js самой страницы словно заморожена скрипт кнопку 2 не видит (кнопку 1 нажимает только). Но если руками в консоли вводить команды нажатий, то все ок.

Пытался добавить паузу в 1-5 сек не помогло, ждал кнопку в бесконечном while, тоже не помогло

Comment: Покажите код модульного окна

Comment: это сторонний сайт нет исходников кроме html а сюда их кидать думаю бесмысленно)

Comment: @Atooot Но мы не сможем Вам помочь, если нет чёткого понимания в чём конкретно причина. Это `iframe`, модальное окно, и так далее. А так же посмотреть почему у Вас не выходит выполнить нажатие на кнопку. Либо может помочь `timeout`, либо смотреть чуть глубже. В текущем состоянии на Ваш вопрос невозможно ответить объективно.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/automatically-pause-on-any-exception

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted но это не ваш случай, т.к. (с) Но если руками в консоли вводить команды нажатий, то все ок.

Comment: вот код всплывающего окна`<div class="craft-popup__content">
<div class="craft-popup__header">Серебряный</div>
<div class="craft-popup__hint">Содержимое кейса</div>
<div class="craft-popup-controls">
<div class="craft-popup-controls__button craft-popup-controls__button--open button">Открыть</div>
<div class="craft-popup-controls__button craft-popup-controls__button--upgrade button button--alternate">Улучшить за 30 &nbsp;<span class="icon icon-credit"></span></div>
</div>
<div class="craft-popup__hint">Открытие 8 ч.</div><div class="craft-popup__close"></div></div>`

Comment: а сама ошибка с консоли жалуется именно на нажатие кнопки 2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined at ClickButton (<anonymous>:37:139) `document.querySelectorAll("div.craft-popup-controls__button.craft-popup-controls__button--open.button")[0].click();`